# Using EF Code first to populate an unmapped, aggregate property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF code first and have a domain model containing Image records, each of which is uploaded by a User and has one or more Votes.  Votes have a score of 1 or -1.  It's basically the "hot or not" gallery type app - where each image can be given the thumbs up or thumbs down.

I'm trying to display a list of images with the net rating.  However I want to do this as efficiently as possible, ideally with one database call and not using lazy loading.

I've created an unmapped property on my Image class called NetRating.  I want to then populate this.  I'm trying to follow [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553180/how-to-populate-a-property-that-is-not-directly-stored-in-database-with-codefirs) to use a projection to extract the value.  There's an additional complication in that their may be zero votes, and hence I need to ensure 0 is returned here.

```
    public virtual IList<Image> GetListWithNetRating(
        Expression<Func<Image, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<Image>, IOrderedQueryable<Image>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "",
        int pageNumber = 0,
        int pageSize = 0)
    {
        // Get standard list retrieval query from generic repository
        IQueryable<Image> query = base.GetListQuery(filter, orderBy, includeProperties, pageNumber, pageSize);

        // Create projection with images and net rating from votes
        var projection = query.Select(x => new 
        { 
            Image = x, 
            User = x.User,  // - included field seems to be lost when projecting, so specifically re-including it here                
            NetRating = (int?)x.Votes.Sum(v => v.Score) ?? 0,
        });

        // Update aggregate field on image
        foreach (var p in projection)
        {
            p.Image.NetRating = p.NetRating;
            p.Image.User = p.User;
        }

        // Return set of images
        return projection.Select(p => p.Image).ToList();
    }
```

This results in the following error: "Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1004, 0, Related Entities cannot be specified for Entity constructors that are not part of the Query Mapping View for an Entity Set."

Appreciate if anyone can offer advice - or at least translate what that error message is referring too.

Thanks

Andy